# Is there any way to request official feedback on what to do in order to graduate?

Tags: support, beta-phase, graduating-sites

Let's say there's a site that I'd like to see graduate into a full SE site (I'm not going to mention Code Golf here). Now, I'm aware that the answer to "when will we graduate" is "when you're ready."

However, what if I have the question "what do we need to do to graduate?" What if I think we're ready to graduate, and I want to know why we're not? What is the process for asking that?

- Do I ask on its per-site meta? If I do this, I'm not sure it will get the attention by the Official SE Graduation Committee of Officialness™.
- Ask on meta.SO (meta.SE soon)? This doesn't seem right either though, since it's site-specific.
- Something else?

Comment: I think the problem is that if the community consciously does something to "meet the requirements" for graduation it will not be self-sustaining once it graduates and the community goes back to being itself.

Comment: @Mysticial Well, in this specific case I actually think we're quite ready to graduate, and I want to know why we're not ready, but I tried to make the question more general. Of course, this would only apply once the community thinks graduation is near or they are ready. Edited post to be clearer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Do I ask on its per-site meta? If I do this, I'm not sure it will get the attention by the Official SE Graduation Comittee of Officialness™.

This is it. The community team monitors all per-site metas and will respond as needed. In theory, you could also email the team via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page on your site, but it's best to have this sort of discussion in public where it can benefit everybody.

That said... in most cases, there isn't a clearly defined set of steps. There are no hard numbers that, if you hit them, will guarantee graduation. We constantly monitor various site metrics and pay attention to the periodic site evaluations that happen via the Site Evaluation review queue. In many cases, graduation is a "we know it when we see it" (where "it" is a healthy, self-sustaining, active site) kind of deal.

There are a couple blog posts that touch on this as well:

- [When will my site graduate?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)
- [Does this site have a chance of succeeding?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/)

Comment: Alright, thanks. So, if I posted on a per-site meta and then emailed the team with that post, that would work? (I'm really not expecting the team to relentlessly patrol every single per-site meta, so I'm kind of uncertain that they'll notice the post.)

Comment: @Doorknob This kind of request is what I'd call "important but not urgent", so give them some time. Maybe a few days. Otherwise you're just going to come across as impatient. The team is pretty on-the-ball when it comes to checking up on metas, in my experience.

Comment: @Doorknob: My daily schedule includes: patrol a bunch of per-site metas.

Comment: @Jon: Lol, okay, thanks. Anna: Alright, I shall post on the per-site meta soon (when I have more time).

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian There isn't really a well-defined right-or-wrong there.

Comment: Is there any specific tag we should use when [requesting feedback](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/what-does-the-community-team-think-about-our-site)?

Comment: @Troyen There's no specific tag, no. I'll ping someone on the comm team to take a look.